# FX American call option optimal exercise and holding region

Tags: options, black-scholes, american-options, currency, cross-currency-basis

**Problem**

I am considering an American call option which gives a domestic investor the right to buy a unit of foreign currency at a strike of $K$ units of domestic currency. I have an exchange rate $S_t$ in units of domestic to foreign currency which follows
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t}=\mu\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\mathrm{d}W_t,$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are positive constants. I am trying to prove the following relations:

1. If $r_D>0$ and $r_F\leq0$, the option should not be exercised early. I have managed to prove it, see below.
2. If both $r_D$ and $r_F>0$, the option can be exercised early, and for a given exercise boundary $S^{\textrm{Ex}}_t$, I need to also describe the holding region and derive a PDE for the price of the call option in the holding region. I have questions about this part.

i) If $r_F>0$, I know from the inequality I prove in the next section that it is possible for $\max\{S_t-K,0\}$ to be greater than the option price. However, since the inequality that arises does not explicitly involve $r_F$, is there a way to obtain a closed form inequality (if it exists) involving $r_F$ and $r_D$ to cases for optimal exercise? Practically, when would it make sense to exercise?

ii) How would one form the PDE here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Proof for Part 1.**

Under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, $S_t\mathrm{e}^{-(r_D-r_F)t}$ is a martingale, so the discounted $S_t$ (when investing domestically) satisfies $$\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[S_T\mathrm{e}^{-(r_D-r_F)T}\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=S_t\mathrm{e}^{-r_F(T-t)}.$$

Consider a non-negative, convex function $f(\cdot)$ satisfying $f(0)=0$. Then,

$$\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-r_D(T-t)}f(S_T)\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\geq\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[f(S_T\mathrm{e}^{-r_D(T-t)})\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right].$$

By the conditional Jensen's inequality, we have

$$\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[f(S_T\mathrm{e}^{-r_D(T-t)})\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\geq f\left(\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[S_T\mathrm{e}^{-r_D(T-t)}\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\right)=f\left[S_t\mathrm{e}^{-r_F(T-t)}\right].$$

$f:x\mapsto\max\{x-K,0\}$ is non-negative, convex, and $f(0)=0$, so

$$\mathrm{e}^{-r_D(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[\max\{S_T-K,0\}\Big|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\geq\max\{S_t\mathrm{e}^{-r_F(T-t)}-K,0\}.$$

When exercised at $t$, the payoff is $\max\{S_t-K\}$, which is $<\max\{S_t\mathrm{e}^{-r_F(T-t)}-K,0\}$ is $r_F\leq0$, thereby proving part 1.